# Placing 2 buttons and 1 text field - the constraints are to superview and not siblings

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode6, autolayout, ios-autolayout

In Xcode 6 I am trying to place 2 buttons and 1 text field in 1 column, above each other:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

First I select the top button ("Scan...") and set its 3 constraints to 8 pixels:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

This works well.

But when I try the same for the next button ("Connect...") - its top constraint is related to the super view and not to the other button.

I search around in Interface Builder, inspect the constraints properties - but can not find the place to fix that.

Where can I please toggle for a constraint - if it relates to the super view or the sibling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface builder identifies the nearest neighbor as the closest sibling view in the desired direction, **not overlapping**. Thus what might prevent you from adding a constraint between the 2 buttons is that they are overlapping, you should try moving the connect button down.

Another way of adding a constraint between any 2 views is to Ctrl+Clic on a view in the left panel, and release the pointer on the other view of the constraint you want to create.

Comment: Thanks +1. My current problem when I Ctrl-click 2 buttons is negative/positive: I am not sure what to set as First Item, Second Item and +Constant (I try different values there and swap them...) And I wonder about the Y-axis: does it originate at the top and grows down in Interface Builder?

Comment: If you're not sure which view is first or second, you can look at a constraint in a mathematical perspective : A = multiplier * B + constant (where A is an attribute of the 1st view, and B an attribute of the 2nd view). For instance, with a "Vertical spacing" constraint, A is the bottom of the 1st, and B the top of 2nd view, thus a constant of 20 would lead to the second view being 20px under the first. Concerning the axis the convention in UIKit is origin in the top-left corner.

Answer (score 1):

You can CTRL + Drag from the connect button to the scan button to specifically set constraints related to those two buttons.